# masonry/jquery. items do not collapse correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, masonry

I have searched and tried looking for the answer. I think it might be trivial but still couldn't find the error since I am new to using the masonry jquery plugin.

My problem is that the items will not collapse correctly using masonry. I want to use two column sizes (25% and 50%). The website will span across the whole website. I am also using the purecss framework.
Here's the example with placeholder images:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>masonry / purecss test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://npmcdn.com/masonry-layout@4.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid">
 <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
 <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/550x600" alt=""></div>
 <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x500" alt=""></div>
 <div class="grid-item--width2"><img src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt=""></div>
 <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/550x800" alt=""></div>
 <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/550x600" alt=""></div>
 <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x500" alt=""></div>
 <div class="grid-item--width2"><img src="http://placehold.it/750x500" alt=""></div>
 <div class="grid-item--width2"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x500" alt=""></div>
</div>

<script>
 var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
   // use element for option
   columnWidth: '.grid-item',
   percentPosition: true
 });
 $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
   $grid.masonry('layout');
 });
</script>

</body>
```

The css/scss is simple and looks like this:

```css
@import "partials/pure-min";

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
}
.grid-item--width2 {
 width: 50%;
}

img {
 width: 100%;
}
```